# Unable to connect to postgres sql on Kubernetes minikube from Client tool

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have successfully deployed postgres on Kubernetes.

```
postgres                                 NodePort    10.96.66.202     <none>        5432:30030/TCP
```

I am able to connect to postgres using localhost and 5432 with the following command:

```
kubectl exec -it postgres-75b8fd84f-gkj6k -- psql -h localhost -U appuser --password -p 5432 appdb
```

But when I tried to access the psql using another client tool using the node port and minikube IP I am getting the below error:

```
host=$(minikube ip)
192.168.49.2

port=$(kubectl get service postgres -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[0].nodePort}')
30030

$ psql -h 10.96.66.202 -U appuser --password -p 30030 appdb
Password: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on host "10.96.66.202" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 30030?
```

Edit:

I tried the minikube IP as well:

```
$ psql -h 192.168.49.2 -U appuser --password -p 30030 appdb
Password:
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on host "192.168.49.2" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 30030?
```

I also tried this combination as well:

```
$ psql -h 10.96.66.202 -U appuser --password -p 5432 appdb
Password:
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on host "10.96.66.202" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Try using `192.168.49.2` as host instead. `10.96.66.202` looks like a `ClusterIP` which is works inside the k8s nodes only, not outside.

Comment: I tried with the minikube Ip as well, it is giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

The IP `192.168.49.2` is for the node, and `10.96.66.202` is for the service.

And the nodePort `30030` is for the node, and the targetPort `5432` is for the service.

So you can use either

```
psql -h 192.168.49.2 -U appuser --password -p 30030 appdb
```

or

```
psql -h 10.96.66.202 -U appuser --password -p 5432 appdb
```

Comment: updated the output with what you have suggested, but still getting the same error